# SQL join to get field name

Tags: sql, join

I have the following query and I'm looking to write a join to give me the direction of a stock trend based on the id.

```
stock_trends
------------
stock_id
trend_id
direction_id
timestamp
price
breakout_price


trend_direction
---------------
id
direction


select s.*, v.latest_trend_date, 
dbo.GetStockAverageVolume(s.id, latest_trend_date, GETDATE()) 
as avg_volume from stocks s
join(select stock_id, MAX(timestamp)as latest_trend_date from stock_trends st
group by st.stock_id) v on v.stock_id = s.id
where 
(select top 1 trend_id from stock_trends 
where s.id = stock_trends.stock_id order by [timestamp] desc) = 
@trend_id and s.market_id = @market_id
and dbo.GetStockAverageVolume(s.id, latest_trend_date, GETDATE()) > 300000
order by latest_trend_date desc
```

How can I modify the above query to get the direction of the trend based on the direction_id within the stock_trends table?

For example:

```
select s.*, v.latest_trend_date, 
dbo.GetStockAverageVolume(s.id, latest_trend_date, GETDATE()) 
as avg_volume, **direction** from stock s
...
...
...
```

Man I'm bad at joins!

Thanks so much.

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I think your query could be optimized

```
 select stock_id, td.direction, MAX(timestamp) as latest_trend_date
 from stock_trends st
 join trend_direction td on st.direction_id = td.id
 group by st.stock_id, td.direction
```

oh yeah and add v.direction to the main list.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan, this is not quite what I'm looking for. I've tried to add direction id into my subquery and add it to my group by but it changes my result set. Is it possible for me to do a join on direction_id without having to add it to the GROUP BY?

Comment: @robokop - It should not change the result set... the query must look different than you are posting.

Comment: @robokop - Or some of your direction_id fields are null.  Did you check that?